# Accessing synchronized method in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Simple question but I'm not experienced with multithreading.
If two threads use the same *synchronized* method (in Java) and the first thread cannot access the method at given time (because the second one is using it), does the first thread wait (freeze) for some time and then tries to access it again, or does it just give up and don't access it at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method blocks and waits until it can use the method, as per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

> When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.

I'm not 100% sure if I remember correctly, but if memory serves me right the JVM does not give any guarantees as to the order in which threads will be able to acquire the lock after it's been released.

Comment: A good answer links to the documentation and puts a short, relevant quote answering the question, +1.

Comment: ^ Agree. Thanks for the answer. I've been on that page like 4 times today and I haven't noticed that bit. I must do less skim reading and more proper reading.
Also, I only have 2 threads, so order is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read the Java documentation.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Answer (score 0):

It waits.

The JVM will not allow two threads to synchronize on the same object at the same time.  If one thread is already synchronized when a second thread attempts it, then the second thread will be put to sleep and added to a queue.

Whenever a thread releases a lock (i.e., when it exits from a synchronized method or block), the thread at the head of that lock's queue will be waked up, and then it will be allowed to lock the lock.

Comment: are you sure about your last sentence?

Comment: @assylias.  I could only find this in the JLS: "While the executing thread owns the lock, no other thread may acquire the lock."  One efficient and fair implementation of that requirement would use a queue-based lock that would behave as I described.  Other implementations, that might behave differently are allowed, but their behavior might be harder to explain to a noob, and the difference probably is not all that important at this stage in his education.